# Hotkeys for DAT/EM Summit Evolution linking into ArcMap functions instead

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, digitizing, stereo-imagery, arcgis-stereo-analyst

I'm using DAT/EM Summit Evolution to do feature mapping in stereo. When I try to use the hotkeys set in Summit, they instead execute functions in ArcMap.
ie. when I press "0" which is linked to CAD: Close Object in Summit. Instead, it zooms to the map extent in arcmap. 
So far the only way it could be explained to me is that the program is dumb and just does things like that.

Answer: 
The issue was that my first mouse click in the digitizing mode, would make arc the active screen and so the hotkeys would be linked to arc and not Summit. This was due to the DAT/EM summit toolbar in Arc being grayed out. Not sure why it was like that but once the toolbar was active things started working.

Comment: Have you look it up on the company's support for that ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately their website's documentation requires a username and password which I'm assuming is associated with the license which I don't have access to and I've been told it's best to avoid calling them except as a last resort.